# How do I reference a font resource in a satellite assembly?

Tags: wpf, localization, fonts, satellite-assembly

I have a localised WPF application and I need to embed a font for each locale.  I have a font added into my project and it's Build Action is set to Resource.  If I remove the `<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>` from my .csproj (which eliminates the creation of the satellite assemblies) the font is compiled as a resource into the project assembly.  I can then add the font by:

```
<Button Content="My Button" FontFamily="Fonts/#Frutiger LT 87 ExtraBlackCn" />
```

This works perfectly. If I add en-US back into my .csproj the font gets added to the localised satelite assembly. But

```
<Button x:Uid="Button1" Content="My Button" FontFamily="Fonts/#Frutiger LT 87 ExtraBlackCn" />
```

no longer works.

How should I be referencing the localised font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this does not directly answer your question, the MSDN page on [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) seems to recommends that you:

> Create a customized composite font to obtain better control of fonts that are used for different languages.

The idea is that you use a single, "composite", font for that contains the fonts for all languages that you might want to use. For more information on Composite Fonts (including examples), see the [FontFamily Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.aspx) on MSDN.